# Do I need a transit visa for Malaysia?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I am an Indian passport holder travelling from China to India via Kuala Lumpur, on Air Asia tickets bought separately. The layover is 4 hours and 30 minutes.

Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: DO you live in India?

Comment: yes i do live in india

Answer (score 1):

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger documents, states in relevant part:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Nationals of Bangladesh, India, Pakistan and Sri Lanka who
>     reside in country of nationality transiting through Kuala
>     Lumpur (KUL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to
>     a third country on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or Air Asia (AK)   within
>   120 hours. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Australia, China (People's Rep.),   Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or USA, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

You may need to present both of your tickets when you check in at your first flight.

Comment: Correct assuming lives in India

Comment: i am an Indian with a multiple entry Chinese business visa

Comment: @Michael Hampton                                                                                            so you mean that i am qualified for the TWOV (Transit Without Visa) and i should get both of my boarding passes at my check-in in china

Comment: It certainly looks that way.

Comment: @mikezfabulousmikey Correct

Comment: @Michael Hampton and Crazydre thank you for the advice