# Do I need a transit visa in the Kuala Lumpur airport to visit the city? I’m travelling to Thailand from India through Air Asia Airlines?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia, airasia

I am travelling to Thailand from India for vacation and have 10 hours of layover at Kuala Lumpur airport by Air Asia.
To visit near by places outside airport do I need the Transit Visa?
If yes then how I can get it?
Kindly assist.

Comment: To answer we need to know your citizenship. This question may be relevant https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129222/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-malaysia?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Traveller: Just to clarify my doubt. Do you mean I can transit without visa in Kuala Lumpur and travel the city. Because In Thailand I will be getting Visa on Arrival.

Comment: Again, what country issued your passport?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I have Indian Passport.

Answer (score 1):

As an Indian national you can transit without a visa as explained here [Do I need a transit visa for Malaysia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129222/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-malaysia?r=SearchResults)

You need a visa if you want to leave the international transit area of Kuala Lumpur airport on your outbound journey. Depending on your itinerary you may be eligible for Visa on Arrival on your return trip (Indian nationals arriving from a third country which are Thailand, Singapore and Indonesia).

https://www.vfsglobal.com/malaysia/india/wrf2.html